# Ant Script to Add Clearcase Labels to Elements without Labels

Tags: ant, clearcase

I am trying to create an Ant script that will create a label in ClearCase and then apply the label to the latest version of any file where the latest version does not have a label.

I am using this to create the label:

```
<ccmklbtype typename="${label.name}" failonerr="false" 
 ordinary="true" comment="${label.comment}"/>
```

When I use this to add the labels:

```
<ccmklabel viewpath="${view.path}" comment="${label.comment}" recurse="true"
 typename="${label.name}" replace="false" version="\main\${side.branch}\LATEST"/>
```

It is, of course, adding the label to everything in the view path.  My desired behavior would be to only add the label if the item doesn't already have a label on the latest version.

I can do what is desired via a command prompt, but I am trying to see if it can be done via Ant.

Does anyone have any ideas?

It looks like there is not a way to just label something that doesn't already have a name.  Instead, I set it up to use an exec block in ANT that will label anything if it isn't labeled already with one of the labels used previously:

```
<target name="add_labels" description="Look for LATEST code that does not have a previous version label already on it.  Skip the 0 generation as that is brought in from a previous release.">
<exec executable="cleartool" dir="${view.path}">
<arg value="find" />
<arg value="." />
<arg value="-ver" />
<arg value="version(\main\${side.branch}\LATEST)&amp;&amp;!version(\main\${side.branch}\0)${history.check}" />
<arg value="-exec" />
<arg value="cleartool mklabel -replace ${label.name} %CLEARCASE_XPN%" />
</exec>
</target>
```

It seems to work in testing.

Comment: Why not use `replace=true`? that would put a lavel to all elements, with or without label, and put it on the latest version. What command-line (`cleartool`) are you using to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [man page of `ccmklabel`](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/ccmklabel.html), you see:

> `replace  bool`
>   If `true`, allow the replacement of a label of the same type on the same branch.
>   The default is `false`.

So with `replace=true`, if a file hasn't a label on the latest version, it will be put (or moved to) said `LATEST` version.

---

In the [OP ruminator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413502/ruminator)'s case,  he only wants to add a label if the version does not have one already.

2 approaches are possible:

- `ccmklabel` in a view which already select only the versions you want to label.
  Hard to do since the only **[version selector](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/version_selector.htm)** usable in a config spec is `\main\${side.branch}\'{!lbtype(MY_TEST)}`, which select the last version which isn't labelled '`MY_TEST`' (and that doesn't fit exactly the initial selection criteria)
- don't use ccmklabel in the ant script, and call insteald directly a cleartool find directive (which is more precise and can combine more version selectors than in a view config spec).
  That is what the [OP ruminator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413502/ruminator) illustrates in his question update:

The find query focus on `LATEST` versions which haven't the right label:

```
<exec executable="cleartool" dir="${view.path}">
  <arg value="find" />
  <arg value="." />
  <arg value="-ver" />
  <arg value="version(\main\${side.branch}\LATEST)&amp;&amp;!version(\main\${side.branch}\0)${history.check}" />
  <arg value="-exec" />
  <arg value="cleartool mklabel -replace ${label.name} %CLEARCASE_XPN%" />
</exec>
```

Comment: I read that man page to indicate that the old label will be moved to the latest version. I am hoping that I just didn't understand it properly. I can't wait to test (but it won't be until Wednesday).  Thanks.

Comment: This didn't do what I was hoping.  Having the replace="true" just made it so that versions that have a label just got the new label (seems to be the same behavior).  I only want to add a label if the version does not have one already.  We are using the labels to identify what CIs changed between releases (which is why we only want to add a label if the LATEST version doesn't have one).

Comment: @Ruminator then build the view on which you will call your `ccmklabel` in order to select only the elements you want to label: look at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/version_selector.htm and see if you can come up with a selector which would select only the versions that you want. use that view to apply your `ccmklabel` command.

Comment: It looks like there is no shortcut or query for the latest version without a label. Now I know why the old .bat file implementiaton keeps a running list of all of the labels ever used.  When I tried to use a query from inside of Ant _version="\main\${side.branch}\'{!lbtype(MY_TEST)}'"_, though, it failed (saying it couldn't find that).

Comment: @Ruminator no, you need to setup a (dynamic) view first: nothing to do with ant. *Then* your ant script can use this view.

Comment: @Ruminator perfect, that means it is easier to change/update its config spec. The challenge, however, is to make the right config spec to select only the versions you want to label (with your ant script).

Comment: please see my update above.  I think it accomplishes the goal.  the _${history.check}_ is a running list of label names to exclude:  _&amp;&amp;!lbtype(MY_OLD_LABEL})&amp;&amp;!lbtype(MY_NEWER_BUT_STILL_OLD_LABEL})_.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Ruminator sounds like a great alternative: I have documented it in the answer for more visibility